# Как взять список каналов youtube на которые вы подписаны

Tags: html, веб-программирование, youtube, web-scraping

Мне нужно реализовать сбор именно некоторых данных со страницы.На каком языке это можно сделать.
Суть в том что хочу сделать прогу, что будет брать с вашего аккаунта ютуб список людей на которых вы подписались и например при запуске или раз в сутки проверять от чего ютуб вас отписал самостоятельно...
Надеюсь на помощь, так как я лишь начинаю свой путь программирования..

Comment: «На каком языке это можно сделать» — на любом, который умеет ходить в интернет.

Comment: Если вас интересует именно решение задачи получить от ютубе данные, лучше переформулируйте вопрос именно так, чтобы увеличить шансы получить ответ. Сейчас ваш вопрос слишком общий и не может иметь однозначного законченного ответа.

Comment: [Youtube API: subscriptions](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions/list)